# Swift: filtering objects - use symbols for precision searching

Tags: swift

Curious to know if Swift permits the use of search operators like the wildcard "*" or the exclusive "-"  or Boolean search operators like AND, OR and NOT.  By search operators I mean symbols an app user would input into a text box to narrow a search.  I think  NSPredicate's LIKE allows the use of "*" and "?".  But I have not come across online examples of search operators used in connection with swift's often cited filtering code:

```
object.filter{$0.objectProperty.contains(searchText)}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction of some literature I would be grateful. I would be interested to learn how to make it possible for an app user to use search operators referenced above and/or use something like the following to narrow a search:  dog w/20 food

The latter search term would find all instances of "dog" within 20 characters of "food."

Comment: You can still use && and || while filtering

Answer (score 1):

[The filter on Swift's array](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688383-filter) Is simply a method that returns it's own type, using a passed function that returns a Bool. So the short answer is, there's nothing related to the "filter" function that allows you to do anything like what you're talking about.

One common way to filter/find things is to use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) which are supported by Swift. ([You can search here for more specific info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift+regex)).

If you have everything in a database and expect your users to know how to write Predicates, I suppose you could use CoreData and search with a string from the user, but that seem pretty unlikely.

Outside of those options you will probably need to search for a third party library or build some sort of parser yourself.